# How can i subscribe to an url inside an array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i subscribe to an url inside an array in angular

I'm studying the SWAPI API and angular, and i want to know how can i get the list of starships NAMES on the html. I can get the list of the people names from the api, and the list of the URLS, but the starships are inside an url inside the array. How can i access them?

i have a stackblitz link with some of the work:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3cqfsb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question, and not just a link to the code.

Comment: `*ngFor="let starship of people.starships"`

Comment: Using the *ngFor="let starship of people.starships" will list me list of URLs, inside the json, what i want to know is how i can get the each ship name, for that i need to access the URL, how can i do that?

Comment: You can fetch all starships through an observable and use a custom pipe to filter out those related to the person. https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `async` pipe within the template, we can do most of the work in the template like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box" *ngFor="let person of data.results">
      <p>
        <strong>name: </strong>
        <br />
        {{ person.name }}
      </p>
      <p><strong>Starships:</strong></p>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let ship of person.starships">{{ ship.name }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button name="previous" (click)="pagination(data.previous)">
      previous
    </button>
    <button name="next" (click)="pagination(data.next)">next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next you will use the component as a middleman to communicate between the template and the service:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  // Using a template pipe, unsubscribe will happen automatically 
  data$ = this.peopleService.data$;

  constructor(private peopleService: peopleService) {}

  pagination(url: string) {
    this.peopleService.go(url);
  }
}
```

Next in the service we define a `data` behavior subject which will contain the initial url to load.

I created two observables `ships$` which will load each ship for each person, and `person$` which will go through each person and pass that person to `ships$`.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class peopleService {

  private readonly rootURL = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/';

  ships$ = (person: Person) =>
    of(person.starships).pipe(
      // Since i is an array each item will be returned to the next function
      concatMap((i: string[]) => i),
      // i is now a string from the previous function
      concatMap((i) => this.http.get(i)),
      // Once all urls complete convert the result back to an array
      toArray<Starship>(),
      // Replace the string version of the array with the object version
      tap((i) => (person.starships = i)),
      // Pass person on to the next function
      map(() => person)
    );

  people$ = (people: Person[]) =>
    of(people).pipe(
      // Read each array item as a string and pass it to the next function
      concatMap((i) => i),
      // i is now a Person object we will pass it to ships
      concatMap((i) => this.ships$(i)),
      // convert the results back to an array
      toArray()
    );

  data = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.rootURL);
  data$ = this.data.pipe(
    // Process the value of the behavior subject
    concatMap((url) => this.http.get<Results>(url)),
    concatMap((result) =>
      // Send the results to the people func for processing
      this.people$(result.results).pipe(
        // Map back to the original with strings replace by objects
        map<any, Results<Starship>>(() => <Results<Starship>>result)
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  go(url?: string) {
    // This will trigger the `data` pipe to run again
    this.data.next(url || this.rootURL);
  }
}
```

Here are some example `interfaces` that were used:

```js
interface Results<T = string | Starship> {
  next: string;
  previous: string;
  results: Person<T>[];
}

interface Person<T = string | Starship> {
  name: string;
  starships: T[];
}

interface Starship {
  name: string;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-starwars-http

[image: Result]

Comment: Right, this gets the string of the URL, but doesnt really acess the name of the ship right?

Comment: Give me a moment, I am updating the code

Comment: @Fdamaso I have updated the answer with working code.

Comment: thanks man, i'll try to study the code!